# Scrape all values from local html file in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, scrape

I have html (locally) file that looks like this:

[image]

Would be someone so kind and show me how to approach this, scraping few lines given this kind of layout?

This is one of many unsuccessful trials:

```
library(XML)
example.html <- scan(file=file.choose(),what="character")
parse.html <- htmlTreeParse(example.html, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xpath.val <- xpathApply(parse.html, '//div', xmlValue)
g.val <- gsub('\\s', '', xpath.val)
```

If someone would be interested to see the html file itself is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/html1)

EDIT: Of course I don't expect anyone to solve this whole issue. I would be happy with any thought as to where to look.

Comment: That's very badly formed html, too bad. What values do you want?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this!In fact all values, preferably extracted into data.frame

Comment: HTML link is down, this question doesn't have any value for future readers anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this doesn't get you quite all the way there, but maybe this helps

```
library(XML)
library(stringr)
namespaces=c(xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2008/inlineXBRL")
parse.html <- htmlTreeParse("~/Downloads/html1.html", useInternalNodes=TRUE)
tt <- xpathApply(parse.html, '//tr[@class="iris_table_row"]', namespaces=namespaces)
foo <- function(x){
  vals <- sapply(xmlChildren(x), xmlValue)
  str_trim(vals[names(vals) %in% "td" & sapply(vals, nchar)>0], "both")
}
rows <- lapply(tt, foo)
rows[170:175]

[[1]]
 td 
"%" 

[[2]]
                td                 td 
"Class of shares:"          "holding" 

[[3]]
        td         td 
"Ordinary"   "100.00" 

[[4]]
            td             td 
      "Page 5" "continued..." 

[[5]]
                                                      td 
"Whitton Park Estates Limited (Registered number: 00231549)" 

[[6]]
                                         td 
"Notes to the Abbreviated Accounts - continued"
```

Comment: This is all I need. I can work with this. Thanks a million!